# Other way to write this query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables STAT1 and STAT2 with the same structure and column names. I use STAT1 to load the latest CSV file, the rest of them get loaded to STAT2. The database is only for statistics, the columns that matter here are: function, value and username. I'm getting the average response time for every function the user has used when there's a problem and comparing it to the average response time for the week prior.
here is the query:

```
select a.functions,    
       avg(a.value), 
       avg(b.value)
  from STAT1 a, 
       STAT2 partition (p9) b
 where a.functions = b.functions
   and a.username = '<USERNAME>'
 group by a.functions
 order by a.functions desc;
```

The query works fine but takes a long time. Any other way to accomplish the same result?

Any input would be great and thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have an indexes on the tables?

Comment: No but I'm going to add some since this took over 10 minutes, any suggestion on what columns? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to calculate the average function value independently of the current set of stats since the join can skew the averages. (Without seeing the data, I'm thinking you can get >1 row repeated from either table.)

You may want to consider something like:

```
select a.functions,    
       avg(a.value), 
       (select avg(b.value) 
          from STAT2 partition (p9) b 
         where b.functions = a.functions
       ) as overall_fn_avg
  from STAT1 a
 where a.username = '<USERNAME>'
 group by a.functions
 order by a.functions desc;
```

or

```
select a.functions,    
       avg(a.value), 
       max(b.overall_fn_avg)
  from STAT1 a
       inner join
       (select s2.functions,
               avg(s2.value) as overall_fn_avg 
          from STAT2 partition (p9) s2 
         group by functions
       ) b
         on b.functions = a.functions
 where a.username = '<USERNAME>'
 group by a.functions
 order by a.functions desc;
```

Comment: I just tried it, worked perfectly and was a lot quicker. I really appreciate it, thank you so much :).

Comment: @mike; indexes... put some indexes on `a.username, a.functions` and `b.functions` for starters and watch this speed up a lot more.

Comment: If adding indexes, then it can also add to previous indexes a.value and b.value columns and gain even more by not going to tables at all (or switch structure by using IOT can be interested in cases not to have heap table + index...). It's good to know that it's compromise between insert cost vs read cost. In OP case, maybe just a.username, b.functions is enough...